# Handling Errror Response with Moshi

Tags: android, json, moshi, custom-error-handling

in my Android app, after sending some registration credentials I get the following JSON output from the server:

```
{
"response":"successfully registered new user",
"email":"testing@gmail.com",
"username":"testing",
"id":9,
"token":"98d26160e624a0b762ccec0cb561df3aeb131ff5"
}
```

I have modeled this using the `Moshi` library with the following data class:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Account (
    @Json(name = "id")
    val account_id : Long,
    @Json(name="email")
    val account_email: String,
    @Json(name="username")
    val account_username: String,
    @Json(name="token")
    val account_authtoken : String,
    @Json(name="response")
    val account_response : String
)
```

Everything works fine. Now I wanted to handle error cases. When I get an error (let's say, the email I want to register with already exists) then I should get a JSON output like this:

```
// what the app gets when there is some error with the credentials
// e.g. email exists, username exists etc.  
{ 
"error_message" : "The email already exists", 
"response": "Error"
}
```

The method that executes the request looks like the following:

```
override suspend fun register(email: String, userName: String, password: String, passwordToConfirm: String): NetworkResult<Account> {
        // make the request
        val response = authApi.register(email, userName, password, passwordToConfirm)

        // check if response is successful
        return if(response.isSuccessful){
            try {
                // wrap the response into NetworkResult.Success
                // response.body() contains the Account information
                NetworkResult.Success(response.body()!!)
            }
            catch (e: Exception){
                NetworkResult.Error(IOException("Error occurred during registration!"))
            }
        } else {
            NetworkResult.Error(IOException("Error occurred during registration!"))
        }
    }
```

If the response is successful, then it wraps the `response.body()` into `NetworkResult.Success` data class.
My `NetworkResult` class is a sealed class with two sub data classes `Success` & `Error`.
It looks like this:

```
// I get the idea for this from https://phauer.com/2019/sealed-classes-exceptions-kotlin/
sealed class NetworkResult<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : NetworkResult<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : NetworkResult<Nothing>() 
}
```

But that does not handle the JSON output for errors I mentioned above. When the app gets the error JSON output, `Moshi` complains that the `Account` data class does not have a `error_message` property which is clear to me because I do not have such a field in my `Account` data class.

What do I need to change so that I can also handle any error cases I wish ? I know, I could model a second data class and call it `Error` with the fields `response` and `error_message` but my sealed class `NetworkResult` only accepts one class as generic type.

So, what can I do ?

Comment: there are many ways to fix it, either add the field and a flag to error and account results or can create custom Moshi adapter or do the mappring of raw result conditially using mappers etc

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialise a value to a field in data class, Moshi will consider it as a required field.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Account (
    @Json(name = "id")
    val account_id : Long = 0,
    @Json(name="email")
    val account_email: String = "",
    @Json(name="username")
    val account_username: String = "",
    @Json(name="token")
    val account_authtoken : String = "",
    @Json(name="response")
    val account_response : String = "",
    @Json(name="error_message")
    val error_message : String = ""
)
```

Like this you can create the same data class for Success and Error both.